# Long term spectral flatness measure voice activity detection

Tags: signal-detection, speech-processing

This is the Long term spectral flatness measure code that I have written so far. Can someone please help me, I don't know if I'm writing it correctly. It is  working fine and gives high peak for speech region and sometimes output high flatness for regions where it should actually give high peaks.

```
nfft = 1024;
s_bin = ceil(nfft*(500/fs))+1;
e_bin = ceil(nfft*(4000/fs));

[S]=spectrogram(signal_zpad,hann(frame_length),frame_shift_length,nfft,fs);

M = 10;
R = 30;
spec_size = size(S,2);

SS(1:spec_size) = 0;
AM(1:e_bin) = 0;
GM(1:e_bin) = 1;
RR(1:spec_size) = 0;

for m=1:spec_size
    for wk=s_bin:e_bin
        for n=m-R+1:m
             if n>0 
                c = 0;
                for p=n-M+1:n
                    if p>0
                    SS(n) = SS(n) + abs(S(wk,p))^2; c=c+1;
                    end
                end
                if c<M
                    AM(wk) = AM(wk)+ SS(n)/c;
                    GM(wk) = GM(wk)*(SS(n)/c);
                else
                    AM(wk) = AM(wk)+ SS(n)/M;
                    GM(wk) = GM(wk)*(SS(n)/M);
                end
                SS(n) = 0;
             end
        end
        if m<=R && c>0
            AM(wk) = AM(wk)/m;
            GM(wk) = nthroot(GM(wk),m);
        elseif m>R  
            AM(wk) = AM(wk)/R;
            GM(wk) = nthroot(GM(wk),R);
        else
            AM(wk) = 0;GM(wk)=0;
        end
        RR(m) = RR(m) + log10(GM(wk)/AM(wk));

    end

        L(m) = RR(m);

    AM(1:e_bin) = 0;
    GM(1:e_bin) = 1;
    RR(m) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try and implement the adaptive threshold method:
This is taken from the EURASIP Paper which i have implemented.

UnlikeM and R, a fixed threshold would lose its efficiency
when facing varying acoustic environments. Therefore, it
is more suitable to design an adaptive threshold [22]. From
Equations 2 to 4, we can conclude that (R +M−1) frame
(0.39 s for fixed R = 30 and M = 10) information is
needed to acquire the first LSFM feature value. In our
implementations, the initial 1.39 s of the test signal x(n) is
always assumed to be non-speech. From this 1.39 s of x(n),
100 realizations of LN can be collected and saved to ψINL.
The threshold is initialized to be
THRINL = min(ψINL). (8)
To update the threshold at the mth frame, we used two
buffers ψS + N and ψN. ψS + N stores the LSFMmeasures
of the last 100 long windowending at themth frame which
was decided as containing speech; similarly, ψN stores
the LSFM measures of the last 100 long window ending
at the mth frame which was decided as including nonspeech
information only. The adaptive threshold for the
mth frame is then updated as:
THR(m) = λ×min(ψS+N)+(1−λ)×max(ψN), (9)
where λ is the parameter of the convex combination. We
experimentally found that λ = 0.55 results in the maximum
accuracy rate in VAD decisions over the TIMIT
training set.

Comment: Looks like you are an expert in the field and have probably come across/thought of this,however maybe this may help.This wont change the peaks, but perhaps it will change your threshold to adapt to the unusual peak.Hope this helps.

Comment: On running your code, Im getting similar values as yours. I am assuming the author of the paper has missed out on particular details.I assumed I hadn't implemented it correctly, but after running your code I am sure certain things in the paper which aren't so explicitly explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt form my code.

```
 x_axis=[1:num_frame];
for i=1:num_frame
 frame(1:len_frame,i) = x(len_frame*(i-1)+1:len_frame*i,1);
 %ene(i)= sum(frame(1:len_frame,i).* frame(1:len_frame,i));
end
segmentLength=len_frame;
noverlap=len_frame/2;
l=pwelch(frame(:,123),segmentLength,noverlap,512);
XK2=[];
for i=1:num_frame

XK2(:,i)=pwelch(frame(:,i),segmentLength,noverlap,512);

end
XK2;



lengtha= length(XK2(:,9))
SN=zeros(lengtha,num_frame);
for i=1:num_frame
  if(i-M>=0)
  for n=i-M+1:i
  SN(:,i)=XK2(:,n)+SN(:,i);
  end
   SN(:,i)= SN(:,i)/M;

  else
  SN(:,i)=XK2(:,i);
  end 

end
% R=10;
SN;
SN2=SN';
SN2(123,:);
l1=length(SN2(1,:));
=-1.5;
SFM=[]
% phi_speech=[];
% phi_nonspeech=[];
count_speech=1;
count_nonspeech=1;
for i=1:num_frame
TEMP=[];
if(i-R>=0)
   for n=i-R+1:i
      TEMP=[TEMP ; SN2(n,:)];

   end

    GM=geomean(TEMP);

    AM=mean(TEMP);
   SFM(i,:)=GM./AM;
    else
    SFM(i,:)=ones(1,l1);
    end

end

len=length(SFM(2,:))
SFM=SFM';
SFMDB=log10(SFM);
L1=length(SFM(:,2));
lx=[];
th=0;
count=0;
th1=[];
for i=1:num_frame

lx(i)=sum(SFMDB(:,i));
if(lx(i)==(-Inf))
    lx(i)=-100;
end

%     if(ref(i)==1)
%         th=th+lx(i);
%         count=count+1;
%         th1=[th1 lx(i)];
    %     end
%         
 end
lx
th=th/count;

thresh=-10
thresh1=-20.5;
th_plot=[];
voice_flags=[];
% lam=0.295;
% phi_seech=NaN.*ones(1,100);
phi_speech(1)=thresh;
phi_nonspeech(1)=thresh;
c1=10;
% phi_nonspeech=NaN.*ones(1,100);
for i=1:num_frame

 th_plot=[th_plot thresh];
if(count_speech==c1)
    count_speech=1;
end
if(count_nonspeech==c1)
    count_nonspeech=1;

end

   if(lx(i)<0)
      if(lx(i)<thresh)
      voice_flags(i)=1;
      phi_speech(count_speech)=lx(i);
      count_speech=count_speech+1;
      else
      voice_flags(i)=0;
      phi_nonspeech(count_nonspeech)=lx(i);
      count_nonspeech=count_nonspeech+1;
  end
  else
  voice_flags(i)=0;
   end
   thresh=lam*min(phi_speech)+(1-lam)*max(phi_nonspeech);

end
```